# Creating a thumbnail of a complex svg graphic in the client

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

I have a website which creates complex svgs  based on input parameters. To store certain input parameters I want to save the chosen parameters along with a thumbnail to the server. I don't want to create the thumbnail on the server as the svgs can become quite big (up to 20MB, compressed still >2MB) and i dont want to send that much data to the server.

When i create the thumbnail on the client side via a canvas the UI becomes unresponsive for a couple of seconds. I tried to use Webworker yet it seems there is no way to draw the svg on the canvas in the worker. I don't need a high quality thumbnail so I hope there is another way of creating a thumbnail of the svg on the client which is faster than going over a canvas.

Comment: Have you tried <use>? Something like http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/examples/MapWithDynamicMiniView.svg but static, which is basically an <svg id="fullsizeSVG">...</svg> with a nested <svg width="100" height="100"><use xlink:href="#fullsizeSVG"/></svg> inside.

Comment: thanks erik, very interesting example yet i need a thumbnail of the whole graphic

Comment: You haven't said how you are creating the thumbnail.  If you post the code you are using, we may be able to suggest ways to speed it up.

Comment: Thanks BigBada, the problem is i am searching for a way to create a thumbnail, the way i do it now is using canvg .

Comment: Perhaps you could be more specific regarding how you need to use the thumbnail. Like, is it only needed for clientside display, or do you need it uploaded somewhere etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach may be to create an svg root element that represents all thumbnails( for instance, its only element could be just the text "SVG"). Then include all the parameters, as attributes, at its svg root, for whichever full sized svg it represents, and send it to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Francis yet i need a thumbnail of the actual svg graphic, somehow ;-)